# Must constant evaluator reject undefined behavior (union example) in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, undefined-behavior, unions

As far as I know, undefined behavior shall be a compile error during constant evaluation.

But if one takes an example of undefined behavior from C++20 standard [class.union#6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.union#6.3) with minor modification to activate constant evaluation:

```
struct X { const int a; int b; };
union Y { X x; int k; };
constexpr bool g() {
  Y y = { { 1, 2 } };   // OK, y.x is active union member ([class.mem])
  int n = y.x.a;
  y.k = 4;              // OK: ends lifetime of y.x, y.k is active member of union
  y.x.b = n;            // undefined behavior: y.x.b modified outside its lifetime,
                        // S(y.x.b) is empty because X's default constructor is deleted,
                        // so union member y.x's lifetime does not implicitly start
  return y.x.b > 0;
}

int main() {
  static_assert( g() );
}
```

then it is accepted by all compilers without any warnings. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W7o4n5KrG

Are all compilers wrong here, or there is no undefined behavior in the example, or no diagnostic is required?

Comment: As far as I understand the standardeze... Reading from y.x.b after y.k =4, would be UB. But writing will make y.x active and this will be fine.

Comment: This appears to simply be a case where compilers do not diagnose UB in constant expressions even though they should. It is far from the only one.

Answer (score 0):

In the original versions of the C and C++ Standards, the phrase "Undefined Behavior" was intended to mean nothing more nor less than "the Standard imposes no requirements".  There was no perceived need for the Standard to ensure that every possible execution of every possible construct as either having unambiguously defined behavior or as being readily and unambiguously recognizable as invoking Undefined Behavior.

Both the C and C++ drafts explicitly state that in cases where the Standard imposes no requirements, implementations may behave "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment".  If there were some execution environment where cache lines were twice as large as `int`, and where storing an `int` value into the first half of cache line and zeroing the rest would be faster than a read-modify-write sequence necessary to update just the first half of the cache line while leaving the remainder undisturbed, an implementation for that platform might process the act of writing to `y.k` in a manner which would disturb the storage associated with `y.x.b`.  On the other hand, for most environments the "characteristic behavior" of writing `y.k` would be to modify an `int`-sized chunk of storage, while leaving the remainder of the storage associated with the union undisturbed.

Treating the act of writing to `y.k` and then reading `y.x.b` as UB was intended to allow implementations to process the write to `y.k` in the fastest fashion, without having to consider whether code might care about the contents of `y.x.b`.  It was not intended to require that implementations make any effort to prevent code from accessing `y.x.b` after writing `y.k`.  Although C++ mandates that integer constant expressions within a template expansion be viewed as substitution failures in cases where they invoke certain actions upon which the Standard would otherwise impose no requirements, requiring that all such actions be treated as substitution failures would create contradictions where the Standard could be interpreted both as requiring that a compiler make a particular template substitution, and as requiring that it refrain from doing so.

Comment: "*Although C++ mandates that integer constant expressions within a template expansion be viewed as substitution failures in cases where they invoke certain actions upon which the Standard would otherwise impose no requirements*" Where is "substitution" coming from here? The standard requires that, during constant evaluation, any evaluation that would lead to UB shall be treated as ill-formed. Constant evaluation can happen outside of template substitution. And yes, this means that compile-time evaluation must diagnose such conditions.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The Standard fails to partition the universe of potential constructs into those whose behavior is unambiguously defined, and those which can be unambiguously determined to invoke Undefined Behavior.  Because the Standard does not forbid implementations from outputting diagnostics beyond those that are required, nor from accepting and usefully processing programs the Standard might characterize as ill-formed, an implementation could in the absence of template substitution issue a diagnostic for any program that could not be proven to be well formed, but...

Comment: ...only reject programs that could be proven to be ill-formed, handling those which couldn't be reliably classified either way by issuing a diagnostic but then processing them anyway.  Inconsistencies in the Standard were thus not a problem.  Template substitution, however, makes it necessary to have a category of constructs that an implementation may unambiguously regard as valid, and a category which may be unambiguously regarded as invalid.  This need could be accommodated by recognizing a category of constructs that implementations may regard as valid or not, at their leisure, but...

Comment: ...the Standard doesn't make such provision in all cases where a construct could neither be proven to be defined nor be proven to invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: What is a "construct" in this discussion? Do you mean a piece of grammar, like `a + b`? Because behavior is not about grammatical constructs; it's about the evaluation of the program. `a + b` may or may not have well-defined behavior; that depends on the types and values of `a` and `b`, based on the rules of expression evaluation. But since constant expression evaluation happens within the implementation, it has 100% of the information needed to know if such an evaluation results in well-defined or undefined behavior. Therefore, it can make any undefined constant evaluation ill-formed.

Answer (score -1):

Huh, I guess it is the compiler being a bit lax - but there is *technically* nothing undefined about this at compile time, as there is no way for `y.x.a` to ever be accessed. Indeed, if you change your definition of `g` to `return y.x.a;` instead of `y.x.b > 0` then it does spit out an error message ("expression did not evaluate to a constant" on my machine).

When a compiler evaluates a `constexpr` expression, instead of compiling the relevant parts of the code it is (universally, as far as I'm aware but don't quote me on that) delegated to an interpreter to evaluate and the constant result is then given to the compiler to be compiled along with the rest of the non-`constexpr` code. Interpreter's are generally far worse at catching what we would call "compile time errors", and so if nothing is actually undefined about the execution of the code, then this is probably good enough for the interpreter. For instance, there is some documentation on the [clang interpreter](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ConstantInterpreter.html) which shows that the execution model is very different to how one would expect the compiled code to run.

Comment: "*there is no way for y.x.a to ever be accessed*" `y.x` is outside of its lifetime. You can't access a subobject of `y.x` if `y.x`'s lifetime has ended.

Comment: Yes, maybe I mean ‘practically’ not ‘technically’. On rereading I admit it sounds like I’m trying to defend the compiler and argue it isn’t undefined behaviour - what I was really trying to suggest was that an interpreter might not be able to detect that it is, as the only information it may have is that it has written to a particular memory location (`y.x.b`) and then read from it, which would seem to be fine from its perspective.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The notion that PODS have a lifetime that anyone should care about, other than the lifetime of the associated storage, adds complexity to the language without serving a useful purpose.  An abstraction in which all storage simultaneously contains all PODS that will fit, but which requires that code associate storage exclusively with a certain type for writing, or not-necessarily-exclusively for reading before accessing it with that type, would allow more useful optimizations while allowing more useful semantics for programmers.

Comment: @supercat: Why do you insist on bringing up irrelevancies in these language-lawyer questions? We all *know* what your position is: the C++ standard is stupid. OK, fine. Can you not move on with your life instead of constantly injecting your opinions into these things? If not, can you please at least stop pinging people about months-old discussions when it's clear that they already know your opinions and don't need to have them reiterated?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Requiring that a compiler to reject a template expansion that involved reading a member of a struct within a union as shown in this example would necessitate a lot of extra complexity, and would also go against the original meaning of Undefined Behavior, to wit, "The standard imposes no requirements".  Do you think the authors of the Standard sought to deliberately mandate such complexity, or do you think they intended not to impose any requirements?

Comment: @supercat: Well, the standard literally says that undefined behavior during constant evaluation is ill-formed, so my guess is "yes, that's what they intended".

Comment: @NicolBolas Does the standard says if a diagnostic is required in that case?  If it just says that the program is ill-formed, according to my understanding, a diagnostic is required... Thus I think that compiler are a bit lazy in their checks here.